# How can I do? $.load into DIV and PHP header to allow access origin

Tags: php, jquery, cors

I'm trying to load an external domain URL into a div. This is my code:

```
<div id="content"></div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#content").load("http://www.domain.com/external.php?query=sentence&callback=?");
});
</script>
```

On the top of External.php, I put:

```
<?php header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");?>
```

But I still can't see the content into the div. Is there anything wrong?

Comment: Why do you have `callback=?` ?. Check your console for errors, and check the network tab that the header is being sent.

Comment: Access-Control-Allow-Origin should be in the file that loads the external URL.

Comment: Hi, Csongor. I did not understand. Please, could you explain it a bit more? Thanks.

Comment: @Csongor Fagyal: Are you sure? The file that loads *is* the origin, and the external file should allow that origin.

Comment: @pimvdb Yes, I agree with you. That's why I get confused.

Answer (score 0):

Your example works for me fine. Keep in mind that not all browsers support cross domain ajax calls. Here is a [list](http://caniuse.com/#search=cors)